# How to force MS Word 2016 to enumerate the figures continuously

Tags: microsoft-word

Although I prefer different processor I'm forced to report results in MS Word.
The report contain many figures (graphs, figures) and few text, mainly comments to the figures and graphs that are broader than captions.

My workflow is to load all figures, then chronologically from fig.1:

- Set wrap to "above and below";
- Put the graphisc into position;
- Resize the graphisc;
- Add caption (automatich numbering);
- Group graphics and its caption;
- Put the graphics in final position.
- If needed align them with surrounding figures.

That way I got my figure numbering ordered this way:

```
     1
     4
   3   2
==new page==
     8
     7
   5   6
   9   10
```

I tried to sort the anchor points of the figures in the right order and then push Ctrl-A; F9 but nothing happened.

Is there any way, how to get the figures correctly enumerated without unnecessary casualties and damages to innocent property?

Comment: Your process seems to be too complicated.  I Generally do 25% of the steps without any issues. Why not just add image to the right place, resize, add caption and forget?  Do you have both in-line and anchored pictures?  Why?  Probably that confuses word.

Comment: The in-liners are just unprocessed ones and are on following page(s).

Comment: Have you tried selecting an individual caption and pressing F9 to update that?

Comment: @Tanya It worken only when I align the anchors in the correct order and then manually select the figure counter and press F9. If I have enough paragraphs on the page to set one anchor to one paragraph...

Comment: What happens when you print the document?  In Word 2010, the fields in the captions in grouped objects all update for me if I press ctrl p to bring up print dialog, and without having to physically print if I return to document the fields have updated.

Comment: @Tanya: Thanks, it works. But in very weird way. I have usually more images than paragraphs. Your advice sort the numbering according to anchor sequence almost correctly. When there are two anchors in one place, it ignores where the images actually are it uses it as a **LIFO stack**...